# Passing wildcards as sqlparameter.Value when performing ExecuteStoreQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am using a database model and trying to query some data using `.ExecuteStoreQuery` function.

My SQL statement looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE f1 LIKE @pr1 AND f2 LIKE @pr2 AND f3 LIKE @pr3
```

Now as you see i use 3 parameters: @pr1,2,3

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery(SQL_string,
new SqlParameter {
  ParameterName = "pr1",
  Value = filterVal1
},
new SqlParameter {
  ParameterName = "pr2",
  Value = filterVal2
},
new SqlParameter {
  ParameterName = "pr3",
  Value = filterVal3 == 0 ? filterVal3.ToString() : "%"
});
```

As you can see, depending on a condition, i want to use either real value of filterVal3 or the wildcard % so in the end when sql statement gets executed it would select records based on the other 2 parameters.

The problem is, the "%" gets translated into something that is not what i am expecting and the query returns empty set. I tried to replace the @pr3 with '%' inside the SQL_string and it actually given me the result i needed.

So how can i get it to work using the SqlParameter?

hope i was clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular problem on and Access DB - there the solution was to replace % with a * in the c# code.
I don't know why it worked though :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your stored procedure

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE f1 LIKE @pr1 + '%' 
    AND f2 LIKE '%' + @pr2 + '%' --if you want to search this way
    AND f3 LIKE @pr3 + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the lack of sleep.

It works as intended actually.
Spent nearly 2 hours googling for this before asking at SO and now my eyes have finally opened.

```
new SqlParameter {
  ParameterName = "pr3",
  Value = filterVal3 == 0 ? filterVal3.ToString() : "%"
});
```

The continional statement here is wrong. I was expecting a value of `filterVal3` to be 0 while i was debugging and in such case, idea was to "ignore" the f3 field when executing query, BUT i accidently switched the true : false and that lead into wrong results.

Correct one is:

```
new SqlParameter {
  ParameterName = "pr3",
  Value = filterVal3 != 0 ? filterVal3.ToString() : "%"
});
```

Sorry guys for wasting your time :(